# Getting Anonymous user when creating user with firebase admin sdk

Tags: node.js, firebase

The issue i am having is that when i create a user using firebase admin sdk the user is created as anonymous user. The data comes from angular to the node.js and the user is even created but as anonymous.

Here is the code

```
const post = req.body;
admin.auth().createUser({
    email: post.email,
    password: post.password
}).then((userRecord) => {
    
    console.log('Successfully created new user:', userRecord.uid);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log('Error creating new user:', error);
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When a user created through the Admin SDK, it is just a Firebase Authentication user profile. It is not tied to any specific provider.

To create  a user account with any specific provider,

- You have to enable the sign-in provider in your Firebase Project > Authentication > Sign-in method
- Use `Firebase SDK` authentication - https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/start

For ex, if you wish to create an user with Email/Password provider,

- Enable the `Email/Password` Provider in Firebase console

[image]

- Use the below snippet for user creation

```js
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
  .then((userCredential) => {
    // Signed in 
    var user = userCredential.user;
    // ...
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    var errorCode = error.code;
    var errorMessage = error.message;
    // ..
  });
```